# Expand parentheses with smartparens

Tags: smartparens, parentheses

I want to expand `else {|}` (second parentheses generated by smartparens) into

```
else {
  |
}
```

which is the best sequence of keys or options?

Comment: There is a very similar question with a nice answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35469843/1365754. With smartparens you can add a local pair to do this. I have one for css-mode for instance: `(sp-local-pair 'css-mode "{" nil :post-handlers '(:add ("||\n[i]" "RET")))`. Then if you press RET when at { | } this will do what you want I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to open a new line with `C-o` then `RET`.